# YouTube API v2 Classic ASP Can't Delete Video

Tags: asp-classic, youtube-api

I'm trying to delete videos using the YouTube API v2. I've been able to upload videos so I believe I'm constructing the requests properly but am having trouble deleting an uploaded video. When I send in the request, I get the following error:

```
400: Bad Request
GDataParseException
Premature end of file.
```

This is what I'm sending via the API:

```
Call objXMLHttp.open("PUT", "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" & strYTUser & "/uploads/" & strVideoID, False)
Call objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("DELETE", "/feeds/api/users/" & strYTUser & "/uploads/" & strVideoID & " HTTP/1.1")
Call objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Host", "gdata.youtube.com")
Call objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & strAccessToken)
Call objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("GData-Version", 2)
Call objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("X-GData-Key", "key=" & strDevKey)
' Call objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", 0)
Call objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8")
Call objXMLHttp.Send("")
```

I'm using the docs for reference and I tried searching but was unable to find something useful so I don't know what I'm missing.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos#Deleting_a_video

Any hints/clues/etc, would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the given example:

```
DELETE /feeds/api/users/default/uploads/VIDEO_ID HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
```

Request call should be as follows:

```vb
objXMLHttp.open "DELETE", "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" & strYTUser & "/uploads/" & strVideoID, False
objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "gdata.youtube.com"
objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/atom+xml"
objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & strAccessToken
objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "GData-Version", 2
objXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-GData-Key", "key=" & strDevKey
objXMLHttp.Send
```

Comment: If you saw my previous comment, please disregard everything. The objXMLHttp.open "DELETE", instead of objXMLHttp.open "PUT" did the trick. Thank you!